# jenkins-pipeline readJSON - how to access nested element

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have trouble accessing nested JSON with readJSON

oldJson string:

```
{"branch":{"type-0.2":{"version":"0.2","rc":"1","rel":"1","extras":"1"}}}
```

I try to access it as in example
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

```
assert oldJson["rc"] == '1'
```

but it fails. I think it because "rc" is nested in "type-02". How could I access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always get the value of a nested element by its nested key using bracket notation or dot notation.

```
stage('Read-JSON') {
    steps {
        script {
            def oldJson = '{"branch":{"type-0.2":{"version":"0.2","rc":"1","rel":"1","extras":"1"}}}'
            def props = readJSON text: oldJson
            println(props['branch']['type-0.2']['rc'])
            \\ or println(props.'branch'.'type-0.2'.'rc')

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Read-JSON)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```